# Converting a Bezier Path with variable width stroke to an outline?

Tags: mathematics, bezier-curve

I started working on a "stylus annotation program", and as part of it I need an algorithm that convert a path with width indicators to an outline. This is similar to the Advanced Outline Layer in the synfig program, and the Power Stroke path effect in Inkscape. I'm looking for a paper describing such an algorithm. Of course I can always read the source code, but I'd prefer a paper to understand the mathematics behind it.

Comment: https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/

Comment: The nearest algorithm I know of is the one Metafont uses for this. I'm not sure if it's nicely summarized in a paper, but there are several chapters in Knuth's *Digital Typography* that provide details. Metafont is available as a "literate program", so the cweb version can generate a full book describing how the program works.